# Angular2 and bootstrap tabs, not sure where\when bootstrap should take over

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular

I want to use bootstrap tab formatting and use within the context of an angular2 component. I'm not sure where I should stop manipulating the `class=` and let bootstrap take over.  It's not working as is, I have a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2u3UWtLne9qOtX3ij6b?p=preview). It doesn't show the first content which I understand. The bigger issue is why does content continue to show after deselection and taking up space. I've been able to manipulate the css class and got it to show and hide correctly, but still takes up space. Given a bare-bones bootstrap tabs example, it doesn't seem like I should go down this route. Set it up, then let bootstrap handle it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I only need the angular tabs component, if the tabs are dynamic which in this case they do are not.  So leave Angular out of it, use bootstrap nav only and move on.